# I need a sql query

Tags: sql

Please find the two tables below

TableB

```
ADq   47             
qww   2.65           
QY    2.26
```

TableA

```
ADq   47             
qww   2.65     
QY    2.39
```

My result should be in this way

```
ADq   47             
qww   2.65           
QY    0.13
```

Thanks
Kishh

Comment: SO programming, the best way to do it without using your brain. You didn't even give details. You just threw some lines out there and hoped for an answer that gives you what you want.

Comment: This seems like you want the difference between 2 row values. Now you need to tell us based on what? What makes the 1 row first, and the other second (a - b)? How are you ordering this, what do you do if there is either of the values missing?

Comment: can you explain the criteria for choosing those entries in the results?

Comment: You need to accept some more answers and explain what you want the query to do. The example leaves a lot of questions unanswered, such as what if there are three instances of `QY`, and what determines the ordering of rows?

Comment: I think he is new and don't know about how to accept or voting system.

Comment: @mahesh 1 year and 10 months, 15 questions

Comment: @Kishh, Do You know about voting system and how to accept the answer?

Comment: Hey guys, one thing you should understand, if the answer is correct i can accept.

Comment: @Kishh, you need to communicate you questions better to get correct answers.  This question is not solvable with SQL.  Also, I don't think you totally understand what you are looking for.  I know `2.39 - 2.26 = 0.13`, but your query is incredibly vague and not logical.

Comment: @Kishh, I find it hard to believe that the community fails to give a correct answer on 85% of your questions.

Comment: can you see the question once again please :)

Comment: FWIW, I came up with this. It's SQL, uses your table and matches the output. It WILL fail if there could be 3 instances of col1.

Comment: SELECT  a1.Col1
            , a1.Col2 - COALESCE( a2.Col2, 0 )
    FROM    TableA a1
            LEFT OUTER JOIN TableA a2 ON ( a2.Col1 = a1.Col1 )
                                          AND ( a2.Col2 < a1.Col2 )
            LEFT OUTER JOIN (             
              SELECT  col1, col2 = MIN(col2)
              FROM    TableA
              GROUP BY
                      col1
              HAVING  COUNT(*) = 2                                                      
            ) a3 ON a3.col1 = a1.col1
                    AND a3.col2 = a1.col2
    WHERE   a3.col1 IS NULL

Comment: @Kishh, You have just edited (and made clear) your question, invalidating the query I gave you. Best to create a new one.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT 'ADq', 47
UNION ALL SELECT 'qww', 2.65
UNION ALL SELECT 'QY', 0.13
```

Comment: That's not a query against Table A!  Good try though.  There's not really much more you can do with this question.

Comment: @JohnB He gave a sarcastic answer to point out that the question is vague.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you only gave us one table: Table A

Secondly, let's say that instead of the Table A that you gave, it had these 5 rows:

```
ADq 47
qww 2.65
QY 2.26
QY 2.39
QY 2.15
```

**What result set would you expect from this SQL query you are asking for?**